# "Not able to post data on published Web API" – 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: .net, iis, cors, web-config

I am using angular 7 and when i post data to web api from local machine it will work but when same  web api i publish on server i can get data from api but i am not able to post data.
I am getting CORS error.

Facing this issue whlie WEB API is published on server.

I have installed CROS nuget package but still i am not able to resolve issue.

I have tried web api changes also installed CORS package also tried Proxy config in Angular but it is not working.

Error: "has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: Hi i am getting this error: http://10.1.5.13:9007/Api/Employee/UpdateEmployeeDetails/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://10.1.5.13:9007/Api/Employee/UpdateEmployeeDetails/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: That’s a response to the OPTIONS request, right? That indicates the server for the `http://10.1.5.13:9007/Api/Employee/UpdateEmployeeDetails/` endpoint isn’t configured to allow OPTIONS requests at all. That’s something separate from CORS configuration.

Comment: for OPTIONS type request i did below code in web api's global.asax file in Application_BeginRequest method as ,             if (Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
                Response.End();
            } but this is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

> I have resolved issue using "proxy.conf.js" insted of
>   (proxy.conf.json) file. Create "proxy.conf.js" file in src folder. and
>   write code as below in "proxy.conf.js".

```
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
var proxyConfig = [{
  context: '/api',
  "target": "http://10.1.5.13:9007",
  secure: false
}];

function setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig) {
  var proxyServer = process.env.http_proxy || process.env.HTTP_PROXY;
  if (proxyServer) {
    var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(proxyServer);
    console.log('Using corporate proxy server: ' + proxyServer);
    proxyConfig.forEach(function(entry) {
      entry.agent = agent;
    });
  }
  return proxyConfig;
}

module.exports = setupForCorporateProxy(proxyConfig);
```

> and change "angular.json" file as,

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AngularTestApp:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
          }

Run NPM start after doing all changes.
```

Answer (score -1):

Download this [CORS browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) for Google Chrome browser and enable CORS when you are hitting the localhost. It should resolve the problem.

You can read more about the cause of this error [here](https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/)

> **Things that might cause this issue:**
>
> - Hitting a server from a locally-served file (a request from file:///YourApp/index.html to http://api.awesome.com)
> - Hitting an external API (a request from http://yourapp.com to http://api.awesome.com).
> - Hitting an internal API (a request from http://yourapp.com to http://api.yourapp.com).
> - Hitting a different port on the same host (webapp is on http://localhost:3000, API is http://localhost:4000)
> - Requesting over http from https or vice-versa (requesting https://yourapp.com from http://yourapp.com)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have also tried CORS plugin for Chrome but it is also not working.